# how to read Extjs dropdown value

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I've written a listener on a button action which adds a dynamic drop-down to my dialog —

```
name : './groupinfo' + count,
id : 'groupinfo' + count,
xtype : 'selection',
type : 'select',
emptyText:'Select a group...',
options : '/bin/groupinfo/options.json', 
fieldLabel : 'Group',
width:200
```

`options.json` sends info in the following pattern —

```
[{"text":"Value1","value":"val1"},
 {"text":"Value2","value":"val2"},
 {"text":"Value3","value":"val3"}]
```

and the drop-down values are showing properly. Now I want to read the selected value in my JS file, but the value is coming out as undefined. I've tried:

```
var dropdownVal = document.getElementById("groupinfo"+i).value;
```

Now, I have tried this which gives me blank value when I select —

```
var value1 = $('#groupinfo'+i+' option:selected').text(); 
alert(value1);
var value2 =  $('#groupinfo'+i).val(); 
alert(value2);
```

When I tried to get the value from the dynamically created *text-box* then I can get the value by using `getElementById` but it is not working for the dynamically created drop-down. Please advise!

Comment: When you say JS file, which JS file is that? And when are you trying to retrieve the values?

Comment: I've mentioed listner logic to add dropdown/text dynamically in my own js file which I included into component. And I'm trying to retrive the values beforesubmit event of dialog. I think I'm missing something to fetch selected values from dropdown because for textfield it is fine. Both the logic to add and retrive are in same js file.

Comment: Did you try `dialog.getField()` or `dialog.findBy()` instead of document.getElementById ?? http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.Dialog

Comment: now I can read the value by using  - document.getElementsByName("./groupinfo"+i)[0].getAttribute("value")

Comment: Thanks rakhi4110 for your help

Comment: Good. But still it appears like it isn't the correct way of getting the value. Better check this across browsers to make sure it is working fine.

Comment: Agree with rakhi4110 its not the correct way of doing it..

Comment: when you say it is not the correct way, then what impact it can have?

Comment: The impact might be one or more from following 1) May not work for across browsers, 2) May not work if the same component is dragged twice onto the page,i.e. setting the value selected in component 1 may reflect changes in component 2. 3) May not work if additional xtypes are added on the dialog or a panel is added on the dialog. 4) May not work for a component inheritance.